# Deploying next-auth app to Vercel creates error in credentials provider

Tags: next.js, vercel, next-auth

I am trying to deploy my next app to vercel. I am using next-auth for authentication with credentials and an api that returns a JWT. On localhost it works ok, but when I put it on vercel, and try to login, nothing happens. However when I view the logs in the project's dashboard functions, there's an error:

```
[POST] /api/auth/callback/credentials
03:32:18:58
2021-12-21T00:32:19.071Z    410db3c3-d841-45d1-8df2-0cdbb4aa8793    ERROR   TypeError: "ikm"" must be an instance of Uint8Array or a string
    at normalizeUint8Array (/var/task/node_modules/@panva/hkdf/dist/node/cjs/index.js:20:15)
    at normalizeIkm (/var/task/node_modules/@panva/hkdf/dist/node/cjs/index.js:24:17)
    at hkdf (/var/task/node_modules/@panva/hkdf/dist/node/cjs/index.js:47:60)
    at getDerivedEncryptionKey (/var/task/node_modules/next-auth/jwt/index.js:99:34)
    at Object.encode (/var/task/node_modules/next-auth/jwt/index.js:45:34)
    at Object.callback (/var/task/node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/callback.js:457:37)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async NextAuthHandler (/var/task/node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:197:28)
    at async NextAuthNextHandler (/var/task/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:40:7)
    at async Object.apiResolver (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils.js:101:9)
2021-12-21T00:32:19.071Z    410db3c3-d841-45d1-8df2-0cdbb4aa8793    ERROR   TypeError: "ikm"" must be an instance of Uint8Array or a string
    at normalizeUint8Array (/var/task/node_modules/@panva/hkdf/dist/node/cjs/index.js:20:15)
    at normalizeIkm (/var/task/node_modules/@panva/hkdf/dist/node/cjs/index.js:24:17)
    at hkdf (/var/task/node_modules/@panva/hkdf/dist/node/cjs/index.js:47:60)
    at getDerivedEncryptionKey (/var/task/node_modules/next-auth/jwt/index.js:99:34)
    at Object.encode (/var/task/node_modules/next-auth/jwt/index.js:45:34)
    at Object.callback (/var/task/node_modules/next-auth/core/routes/callback.js:457:37)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:95:5)
    at async NextAuthHandler (/var/task/node_modules/next-auth/core/index.js:197:28)
    at async NextAuthNextHandler (/var/task/node_modules/next-auth/next/index.js:40:7)
    at async Object.apiResolver (/var/task/node_modules/next/dist/server/api-utils.js:101:9)
RequestId: 410db3c3-d841-45d1-8df2-0cdbb4aa8793 Error: Runtime exited with error: exit status 1
Runtime.ExitError
```

Additional info:
The `SignIn()` function looks like this:

```
signIn("credentials", {
        email: values.name,
        password: values.password,
        redirect: false,
        callbackUrl: `/app`
      })
        .then((data) => console.log("loginpagethen", data))
        .catch((error) => console.log("loginpagecatch", error));
```

I think the problem occurs somewhere in the `jwt callback` function because `authorize` returns a user(with all the data, including jwt from server). Also if I console.log the user in the `jwt callback` function,I can actually see the user object. However the session isn't present.

```
 async jwt({ token, user, account, profile, isNewUser }) {
    if (user) {
      console.log("user", user); //user is there
      token.accessToken = user.token;
    }
    return token;
  },

  async session(session, token) {
    console.log("session", session); //session is not there
    return session;
  },
};
```

P.S. I have added environment variables.

Any idea on how I can get my app to behave on vercel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your .env file creates an environment variable:

```
API_SECRET_KEY=q3t6w9z$C&F)asdfasdfasfasdfasdfasd1sdfasf
```